# To access another user from a remote desktop while admin is logged in Linux in host machine

Tags: vnc, guest-session, hosts, syslinux

Suppose I am logging in as a admin and I want to login as a guest user which is present in the same machine using another remote desktop using any of the services??.I don't want shell using ssh but the whole interface...eg opening a gedit session

Comment: Why not provide the user in the `ssh` command?  what do you mean by *whole interface* as what more do you need than terminal/shell?   But primarily this isn't a generic Linux support site (SE Unix & Linux is that) and you've given nothing on-topic for here - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You may be looking for X forwarding that can be achieved with ssh -x. This way the GUIs of programs you open remotely will be shown on your local machine.

Comment: Sir if I use ssh and opened a shell and typed in gedit it willl open a gedit session in host only I want that to happen in client side.Hope you reply

Comment: I suspect you don't mean remote desktop, you just want to open one application on your current desktop as a different user, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

To run any command as a different user within your current session, the `sudo` command is what you need.

```
sudo user gedit filename
```

should do the trick